# Missing \begin{document} and undefined control sequence for a custom CV class

Tags: errors, documentclass-writing

I am in the process of writing my own class for CV/Resume purposes, with the help of [this website.](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2011/03/27/how-to-write-a-latex-class-file-and-design-your-own-cv.html)  However, when I compile `cv.tex` I get an error of undefined control sequence and also a missing `\begin{document error}`.  Below I have included the code for `cv.tex` and `my_cv.cls` (the class file I am writing). I am unable to figure out what exactly has been causing these errors, but when I build into PDF, I get the desired output but with a blank page preceding it (the error messages do not go away).

cv.tex:

```
\documentclass{my_cv}

\begin{document}

\section{Education}
\datedsubsection{University of Blah}{2016--}

\section{Employment}
\subsection{Blah Blah}

\end{document}
```

my_cv.cls:

```
\NeedsTexFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{my_cv}[2016/07/23]
\LoadClass{article}
\RequirePackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
    {\Large\scshape\raggedright}
    {}{0em}
    {}
    [\titlerule]

\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\large\raggedright}
    {}{0em}
    {}

\newcommand{\datedsection}[2]{
    \section[#1]{#1 \hfill #2}
}

\newcommand{\datedsubsection}[2]{
    \subsection[#1]{#1 \hfill #2}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the first line of your class file. If you compile interactively, LaTeX tells you this.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \NeedsTexFormat
                   {LaTeX2e}
```

The macro should be

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
```

Comment: (the difference is the `X` in `TeXFormat` that must be written with upper case. Took me a while to find it!)